# What is the difference between slugs and pellets for the Winchester?

Tags: dayz-2012

I've found both pellet founds and slug rounds for the Winchester, and tested them both out, but can't really notice any difference between the two.

What's the difference between slugs and pellets?

Comment: Am I the only one who read `Winchester` and remember of the  Winchester's from Supernatural?

Comment: @MichelAyres Nope, haha. First thing I thought of when I found the weapon. I love that show.

Comment: Well, in real life, pellets are more what you'd normally think of when you hear shotgun: small metal BBs which erupt from the barrel in a cone shape. Slugs are more like bullets: a large chunk of metal which fires in a straight line. Whether that's the same in Arma, I don't know, but given the realism of the game, I'd think it would be. I have a friend who plays it, I'll double check with him later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [DayZ wiki](http://www.dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=A_Beginners_Guide#Notes):

> Slugs are solid rounds for shotguns that have decent range and stopping power. Pellets are rounds of buckshot that spread out at short range (about a quarter of the range of slugs). Pellets are more situational, and are probably only superior to slugs in buildings.

Comment: I don't know how it translates to the game, but the last bit there cannot be overstated. In the real world, the techniques used in CQB (close quarters battle) are significantly different from a field engagement. The narrow confines and severely limited sight lines make a weapon that can be reacted with and relied upon to hit, rather than one requiring precious fractions of a second to aim precisely, very valuable.

Answer (score 4):

I think the pellets can kill more than one zombie per shot, if you get the shot right. The slugs have more stopping power and no spread, so they're better for range. Also, I believe they're reducing the power of the 'winnie' so pellets might not be up to the task of one shotting zombies any more.

Comment: What has led you to this conclusion? Also, why do you think they are reducing the power of the winchesteR?

Comment: http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Winchester_1866
and watching a guy kill multiple z in one shot in various episodes of this: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL534AF1D35330EA6E&feature=plcp

Comment: also with slugs only one bullet strike animation is shown, where pellets show a few in a spread, just like a real shotgun, except less pellets

Comment: To kill multiple zombies in one shot, you need two zombies who are very close to each other and far enough away from you so that the spread of the pellets will hit both, but not so far that they don't do enough damage, or spread too far. If the zombies are too far apart then some pellets may go through the gap and therefore not enough damage will be done that way too.

Answer (score 1):

The pellets used in the shotgun spread out like a normal shotgun cartridge does and the slugs are like large bullets.

Comment: Actually in Dayz the Winchester is a shotgun (uses shotgun ammo)

Answer (score 0):

Slugs fire a single, large bullet while pellets fire a number of pellets, I believe around 6 - 12.  The slug deals 4500 points of blood damage, while the pellets deal 2000 per pellet.  Lethal range for pellets is 40m, while with slugs it is 250m.

That said, pellets are the better option.  Because they fire in a spread, you have more of a chance to hit a target even haphazardly aiming.  You're likely to land at least two pellets against your target, which is comparable damage to the slugs.

Most important at all, and I'm going to bold to get the point across, **if a single pellet hits someone in the head they are dead, have a good day.**

And you have a really good chance at accomplishing this, even with piss poor aim, even at 200m away.  Just aim it in the direction you think their head is in and odds are you will hit.  THIS is why pellets are indeed the superior ammunition to slugs.

Comment: This makes zero reference to the game at all.